# How to pass matplotlib plot and axis arguments to a wrapper function

Tags: matplotlib

I want to create a wrapper function that I pass a DataFrame along with some plotting arguments, eg. 'linewidth' and 'xlabel' etc. The problem is that df.plot() method does not accept "xlabel" even though it accepts "title" for example.

```py
def wrapper(df, **kwargs):

   #some axis already created
   ax = self.figure.gca()
   df.plot(ax=ax, **kwargs)

   #now need to set xlabel etc separately
   ax.set('xlabel'="test") # or ax.set_xlabel("test")
```

An idea I had was to create a ax_args (dictionary) variable in the wrapper then unpack this in

```
def wrapper(df, ax_args, **kwargs):

   ...

   ax.set(**ax_args)
```

Looking for advice on how to best achieve this functionality.

Comment: The requirements are not very specific. Why not use `def wrapper(df, xlabel=None, **kwargs)`?

Comment: Yeah it isn't specific just not sure what the best way to do it is. I'll take a look at the ax arguments that i'll need and set them as you suggested

Comment: Of course you can also pass two dictionaries, `def wrapper(df, ax_kw={}, pandas_kw={})` and call it like `wrapper(mydf, ax_kw=dict(xlabel="test",), pandas_kw=dict(linewidth=3,))`

Comment: I think your first idea gives me the desired function calling style i want. Thanks.